# Is there any software that can read w01, w02, w03, file extensions?

Tags: backup, restore

I have got a backup created by Samsung Backup, and it has written files with `w01`, `w02`, `w03` extensions. My Samsung laptop stopped working I don't know how to recover these files.

I have got all files on my external disk. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If the program was created with "samsung backup" then either you need to use that program to recover it, or they have a "samsung recover" program that goes with it.

A lot of these "one off" backup programs that disk manufacturers and computer manufacturers give you use their own unique special format.

Comment: is there any sansung recover program that I can install on other machine like dell , because my samsung laptop is not working

Comment: @CMR - try starting at www.samsung.com

Answer (score 1):

Try opening it with something like 7-Zip. It's entirely likely that it's simply, say a zipped file with a different extension.